# Django Rest Framework I can't use Serializer save model of have foreign key

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django Rest Framework and Django newbie
i can use random data to make stages but i can't use serializer to add new stages.

#### My model and serializer

```
class Stage(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'stage'
    stage_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    stage_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        db_column='id',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
class StageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    stage_id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Stage
        fields = [
            'stage_id',
            'stage_name',
            'company',
        ]
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # create stages
        stage = create_stage(**validated_data)
        return stage
```

#### view.py

```
class StageListAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, company_id):
        data = request.data.copy()
        company = get_company_by_id(company_id)
        data['company'] = company.pk
        serializer = StageSerializer(data=data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        new_data = serializer.validated_data
        serializer.save(company=company)
        return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

#### request.data

```
<QueryDict: {'stage_name': ['kAkSdKq9Gt'], 'company': [6]}>
```

i will receive error:
`TypeError: Object of type Company is not JSON serializable`

i can't understand it and i don't know how to use serializer to save foreign key.

Comment: you need a company serializer too to serialize the model company. I would suggest using viewsets to make post, patch etc. automatic, instead of writing functions for them manually

Comment: i will look viewsets doc, think you

Comment: go through the [tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), they start with [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) then in Later they show how to write [ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/) to combine API Views and refactor your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize the `Company` instance before you can include it in your `StageSerializer`.

A simple example would be something like

```
class CompanySerializer(ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Company
    fields = '__all__'
```

And then to include that in your `StageSerializer`:

```
class StageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    stage_id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    company = CompanySerializer(source='company', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Stage
        fields = [
            'stage_id',
            'stage_name',
            'company',
        ]
```

Comment: sorry，i am first use StackOverflow to ask question.